# Reference request in contact geometry.

Tags: symplectic-geometry, contact-topology

I am looking for an introductory book to contact geometry, as clear and detailed as possible.
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hansjörg Geiges's [*Introduction to Contact Topology*](http://www.cambridge.org/fr/academic/subjects/mathematics/geometry-and-topology/introduction-contact-topology?format=HB&isbn=9780521865852) seems to be the only textbook-style reference on Contact Geometry. (At least it was three years ago, but I'm unaware of a more recent book with this kind of ambition).